# Prove Private Key Encryption Backup is Safe

Tags: backup, encryption, cloud-storage, private-key

Cloud backup services such as iDrive and Acronis offer private key encryption. The important feature is that they offer this service before upload with the ability to store the encryption key externally. This should mean that there is virtually no chance that they would be able to decrypt the files. Is it possible to prove that the key is never sent to either of these companies?

It's at least hypothetically possible that the upload apps could store the key and send it off to the company in a hidden or obscured way. **Is there any way to prove that they don't do this?** I don't think their upload clients are open source.

Comment: thats why people use BYOK configurations (Bring your own Key), and generate them in software that is neither configured to or even able to interface with these services (for instance GPG Kleopatra). Then you must carefully export the public key for delivery to the service. If the service or related software is used to generate or otherwise interact with the private key, then its confidentiality is suspect (it may be fine, but there is no way to prove it).

Comment: That's basically the question I'm asking. Do I need to encrypt before I upload?

Comment: well, that is the only no-trust approach. you can safely provide the service your public key, so that they can encrypt your data (as long as you keep the private key...well,,,private), but if you allow them to do so, their software is touching your unciphered data to transform it into ciphertext, so it depends on whether you trust them to do that or not. if they are the adversary, then you are effectively giving them the data and encryption or not is meaningless.

Comment: I think you're right. I think the only way to do this is bundle the files up in to an archive and encrypt before uploading. I'm using AES 256 with 7zip with a reasonably sized key. Do you know about any security isues with this?

Comment: so the AES 256 spec is fine, provided your passphrase is not stupid, but with crypto software, the devil is in the implementation. even providing that the publisher used well established libraries for cryptographic functionality, integrating those libraries into the program can still lead to bugs that compromise the process or the result. So for 7Zip specifically, I am seeing references to CVEs and vulnerability disclosures, but thats not that uncommon for a lot of software, and the specifics matter. Youll have to look around and see if you can/do trust the implementation enough for your use.

Comment: Chances are 7zip is pretty safe except for the $5 wrench attack. https://xkcd.com/538/